# cakephp - ajax request and action 'edit' does not work in simultaneous

Tags: javascript, ajax, cakephp, view

i'm using  ajax ($this->Js->get) to select an element of any dropdownlist and, then, populate other dropdownlist. but, i have those dropdownlists inside a form->create('User').

So, if i use form->create(false) my action 'edit' doesnt work... on the other hand, if i use form->create('User') my 'ajax' doesnt work.

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('User', array('action' => 'edit')); ?>
<table>
        <tr>
            <th>PROJECT</th>
            <th>VERSION</th>
        </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>   <?php
                 echo $this->Form->select('projects', array($projects), array('multiple' => false,
                    'class' => 'span2',
                    'id' => 'projectsTest'));
                ?>
            </td>     

            <td> 
                <?php
                echo $this->Form->select('projectversions', array($projectversions), array('multiple' => false, 'class' => 'span2',
                    'id' => 'projectversionsTest'));
                ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
</table> 

<?php echo $this->Form->button('ALTERAR', array('type' => 'submit', 'class' => "btn btn-info pull-right")); ?>


<?php
$this->Js->get('#projectsTest')->event('change', $this->Js->request(array(
            'controller' => 'ProjectVersions',
            'action' => 'getVersionsofProject'
                ), array(
            'update' => '#projectversionsTest',
            'async' => true,
            'method' => 'post',
            'dataExpression' => true,
            'data' => $this->Js->serializeForm(array(
                'isForm' => true,
                'inline' => true
            ))
)));


echo $this->Form->end();
?>
```

how can i resolve this problem?

thanks in advance :)

Comment: i'm using 2.3.
but i'm using Js Helper to do the same thing in the 'add' action and it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't this work?

```
echo $this->Form->create(null, array(
    'url' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'edit')
));
```

Comment: doesnt work :(
the edit action works, but the js helepr (ajax) doesnt work. the array it passes 'post' is always null.
the js helper (ajax) works, but he can not get the id of the project and send it by post.